# MySql GROUP BY and ORDER BY deduplication

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a database with the following tables:

```
trips
stores
trips_stores (this table records which stores are visited on each trip)
```

Each visit has a visitStatus:

```
NULL - Not visited
0 - Visit pending
1 - Visited
2 - Skipped
```

I want to return only one record for each store (even though there may be multiple visits for each store). However, I want to return only the **lowest** visitStatus number: NULL, 0, 1 or 2.

For example, my current query returns this:

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| storeID |              storeCity               | visitStatus|  tripDate  |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|     634 | BLACKBURN                            |          1 | 05/17/2014 |
|     634 | BLACKBURN                            |          0 | 07/30/2014 |
|     634 | BLACKBURN                            |          2 | 07/30/2014 |
|     636 | WARRINGTON                           |       NULL | 07/30/2014 |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

But I need it to return:

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| storeID |              storeCity               | visitStatus|  tripDate  |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|     634 | BLACKBURN                            |          0 | 07/30/2014 |
|     636 | WARRINGTON                           |       NULL | 07/30/2014 |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

I've tried various combinations of GROUP BY and ORDER BY but I can't figure it out. Any help much appreciated

My current query

```
SELECT 
    stores.id AS storeID, 
    stores.city AS storeCity,
    trips_stores.status AS visitStatus,
    trips.trip_date AS tripDate
FROM stores LEFT JOIN trips_stores on stores.id = trips_stores.store_id
LEFT JOIN trips ON trips_stores.trip_id = trips.id
WHERE stores.map_display = 1
ORDER BY storeID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `group by` for this or a more complicated query.  With `group by`, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT s.id AS storeID, s.city AS storeCity,
       (case when sum(ts.status is null) > 0 then NULL
             else min(ts.status)
        end) AS visitStatus,
       substring_index(group_concat(t.trip_date order by coalesce(ts.status, -1)), ',', 1
                      ) AS tripDate
FROM stores s LEFT JOIN
     trips_stores ts
     on s.id = ts.store_id LEFT JOIN
     trips t
     ON ts.trip_id = t.id
WHERE s.map_display = 1
GROUP BY storeid, storecity
ORDER BY storeID ASC;
```

Handling the `NULL` values correctly requires a bit of logic.  Because `NULL` is the smallest value -- even when there are other values -- you need to check for that explicitly in the `min()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I get an error Unknown column 'visitStatus' in field list.

Comment: @ginsberg . . . Duh.  *I* knew what I meant when I wrote the query, but it was not correct.  I've fixed it with the correct logic.